# Close QDialog window on button click PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog

How can I close the `QDialog` window once the login button is clicked? Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog_LoginPage(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog_LoginPage):
        Dialog_LoginPage.setObjectName("Dialog_LoginPage")
        Dialog_LoginPage.resize(487, 320)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog_LoginPage)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 30, 491, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(25)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog_LoginPage)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 461, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog_LoginPage)
        self.lineEdit_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 451, 31))
        self.lineEdit_name.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_name.setObjectName("lineEdit_name")
        self.pushButton_confirmLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog_LoginPage)
        self.pushButton_confirmLogin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 230, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton_confirmLogin.setObjectName("pushButton_confirmLogin")
        self.pushButton_cancelLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog_LoginPage)
        self.pushButton_cancelLogin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 230, 111, 41))
        self.pushButton_cancelLogin.setObjectName("pushButton_cancelLogin")
        self.username = ""

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog_LoginPage)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog_LoginPage)

        self.pushButton_confirmLogin.clicked.connect(self.login_clicked)

    def login_clicked(self):
        self.username = self.lineEdit_name.text()
        # Close QDialog Window here
        

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog_LoginPage):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog_LoginPage.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog_LoginPage", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog_LoginPage", "Login Page"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog_LoginPage", "Please enter your name:"))
        self.pushButton_confirmLogin.setText(_translate("Dialog_LoginPage", "Login"))
        self.pushButton_cancelLogin.setText(_translate("Dialog_LoginPage", "Cancel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog_LoginPage = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog_LoginPage()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog_LoginPage)
    Dialog_LoginPage.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried using `Dialog_LoginPage.close()`, `Dialog_LoginPage.accept()`, `Dialog_LoginPage.reject()`. None of these have worked and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's wrong is trying to edit pyuic generated files, which is always discouraged as it's considered a bad practice (you probably had a clear warning about *not editing unless you knew what you were doing* that you decided to ignore and remove). Pyuic generated classes are just helper objects, they are not intended for further editing, but only used as class inheritance or instance composition. Please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html): you'll be able to just call `self.close()` from a properly implemented class.